# Using resultmap of mybatis to collect objects into a linkedhashmap

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis, linkedhashmap

I have two tables:
employee_details(department_id, employee_id) &
skill_details(employee_id, skill_id).
I want to construct LinkedHashMap of Employee_Details objects for each department_id,
such that

```
class Employee_Details {
    long employee_id;
    ArrayList<long> skill_ids;
    // other data & code may be
    ----;
    ----; 
}
```

How this can be achieved using resultmaps in mybatis

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<collection>` and `<resultMap id="" type="java.util.LinkedHashMap">`  like this :

`EmployeeDetails.java`

```
public class EmployeeDetails {
    Long employeeId;
    List<SkillDetails> skillDetails;  // mapping snippet is <collection property="skillDetails" ofType="package.SkillDetails" select="selectSkillDetails" column="employee_id">
    // get set
}
```

`FooMapper.xml`

```
  <resultMap id="EmployeeDetailsResultMap" type="java.util.LinkedHashMap" >
    <result column="employee_id" property="employeeId"/>
    <!-- employee_id as foreign key -->
    <collection property="skillDetails" ofType="package.SkillDetails" select="selectSkillDetails" column="employee_id">
        <result property="employeeId" column="employee_id"/>
        <result property="skillId" column="skill_id"/>
    </collection>
  </resultMap>

  <resultMap id="SkillDetailsResultMap" type="java.util.LinkedHashMap" >
    <result column="col1" property="p1" />
    <result column="etc." property="etc." />
  </resultMap>

  <select id="selectSkillDetails" resultMap="SkillDetailsResultMap" >
    SELECT *
      FROM skill_details t1
      where t1.employee_id=#{employee_id}
  </select>

  <select id="selectEmployeeDetails" resultMap="EmployeeDetailsResultMap">
    SELECT *
      FROM employee_details t1
      where t1.department_id=#{department_id}
  </select>
```

***In the same way, add: **

```
public class Department {
    Long departmentId;
    List<EmployeeDetails> employeeDetails;
    // get set
}

  <resultMap id="DepartmentsResultMap" type="java.util.LinkedHashMap" >
    <result column="department_id" property="departmentId" />
    <collection property="..." ofType="..." select="selectEmployeeDetails" column="employee_id">
      <result property="employeeId" column="employee_id"/>
      <result property="..." column="..."/>
    </collection>
  </resultMap>

  <select id="selectDepartments" resultMap="..." >
    SELECT *
      FROM ...
  </select>
```

*They are all LinkedHashMap,  -_-!

Hope these help...*

Comment: How does EmployeeDetailsResultMap resultmap results into creation of object of class EmployeeDetails? THere is no mapping specified to class EmployeeDetails.

Comment: You can change the value of "type" attribute of `<resultMap id="EmployeeDetailsResultMap" type="java.util.LinkedHashMap" >` to "package.EmployeeDetails".

Comment: Then how would mybatis ensures LinkedHashMap of EmployeeDetailsResultMap is returned? Can you also share the interface file?

Comment: When you have assigned "java.util.LinkedHashMap" to "type" of resultMap, declare function `public List<Map> selectEmployeeDetails();` in the Mapper.java.